# Hive problems of connection to port 10000

Tags: hadoop, hive, connection, mapr

Currently we are running mapr three node cluster where hive is installed and we use it very frequently for analytics and reporting but due to many connection or some other reason hue(UI panel) show error that

"Could not connect to cm:10000"

and after hs2 stop and start(restart) that start working fine what is issue I am really failed to fix it what should I do and how I can fix it

Could not connect to cm:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to     cm:10000',)

its happening very frequently 1 - 2 times in a day .
Please suggest .

Comment: Please suggest me is any way to fix it for permanent basis ?

Comment: You should look at the Hive logs before restarting the process. It's possible that it's having out of memory exceptions and you have to edit the allowed heap space for it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue connecting to Port 10000. Below is the error.

```
WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78 by Apache Hive
```

This forum has several posts about this error already. Common suggestions are:

1. Checking hive.log. I am using HDP but do not know the location of
   hive.log. I checked the path "/var/log/hive" but files in that folder are
   days old.
2. I checked the port using "netstat -an |grep 10000". It did
   not return anything. But I know HiveServer2 is running from the
   Ambari interface. Besides, I am able to connect to HiveServer2 via
   embedded mode.